# Resistor identification of crock pot

Tags: resistors, identification

I'm having a problem with my crock-pot: the device turns on, but when selecting anything, it just turns off. Opened it up, and found the pictures below. I think resistor R49 is the problem - but since I can't find the schematics, I'm in doubt about the value.

[image: Resistor]

[image: PCB]

It seems like brown ? red gold, and I've found an older post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146915/re-building-a-crock-pot-controller-how-are-the-heating-elements-powered/594852#594852) showing the same resistor and having the exact same problem; but  brown red brown gold = 130 ohm. I got a 230V supply, so maybe I can't rely on that value and I have to search the value myself. Question is, how?

Comment: R49 is 1.9K 5%... 2W? Brown, white, red, gold. That pot is poasted.. R49 isn't the cause, I guess.

Comment: Because it is burnt I guess it is also a R-fuse (fuse-resistor) if so do not replace it buy a standard resistor

Comment: To clarify: @francoisP means do not replace it *with* a standard resistor.  If it is indeed a R-fuse type, it must be replaced with the same type.  But: controller for a heating element that you leave unattended in your house for long periods of time?  That burned up once already?  And the replacement is $50?  My advice is to buy a new crock pot.

Comment: My guess would be that R49 overheating like that is a *symptom of the problem*, not the problem itself.

Comment: That and, the heat generated from R49 likely destroyed C8 over time.  You could end up replacing R49, C8, and the other green caps and still not have a functional appliance.  Time to upgrade to a new model.

Comment: I'd go with "new crockpot".  Explaining to your insurance agent that a DIY repair on a $55 crockpot caused your house to burn down would be really bad. Worse, however, is telling the story to your insurance agent in front of your wife. 

Here's the link... https://www.amazon.com/CrockPot-7-0-Quart-Carry-Programable-Cooker/dp/B07HNFZL81

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Replaced resistor R49 with 1.8kΩ 3W and everything seems to work properly.

Comment: _"seems to work"_ isn't enough for something that could cause safety issues. Maybe I'm misunderstanding... can you elaborate some more?

Comment: Ok. I've tested the heating function for a minute and it worked. So far I did not let the cooker overnight.